# How to take the elements of pointer array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I'm trying to make a pointer array which in my case can point to three elements.I want to take the elements at run time and want to access each element but I couldn't. Here is the source code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
    int i;
    float *coefficient[3];
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
        scanf("%f",coefficient[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("%f\n",*coefficient[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `coefficient` is *already essentially a pointer.*  Try declaring   `float coefficient[3];` instead of `float *coefficient[3]`

Comment: @RobertHarvey: They'd also need to remove the `*` in the `printf`, and change the `scanf` to `scanf("%f", &coefficient[i]);` to match. I suspect they declared a pointer array solely because they didn't understand how you're supposed to pass arguments to `scanf` (using `&` to get the address of an existing stack variable typically).

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
float *coefficient[3];
```

to

```
 float coefficient[3];
```

As you need an array of `float` not `float` pointers

Then,

change

```
scanf("%f",coefficient[i]);
```

to

```
scanf("%f",&coefficient[i]);
```

As you need a pointer to the float to read in. Please also check the return value from `scanf`

As you have an array of floats

```
printf("%f\n",coefficient[i]);
```

is what you require

Answer (score 1):

Your pointers are uninitialized, so dereferencing them causes undefined behavior. You need to allocate memory for them, e.g. using `malloc()`.

```
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
        coefficient[i] = malloc(sizeof *coefficient[i])
        scanf("%f",coefficient[i]);
    }
```

And after you print them, you should use `free()` to release the memory.

Answer (score 1):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

You declared an array of three pointers but the elements of the array are not initialized and have indeterminate values.

As a result calling the function `scanf` in this loop

```
for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
    scanf("%f",coefficient[i]);
}
```

invokes undefined behavior.

The pointers which are elements of the array shall point to a valid memory where data may be stored using the pointers.

For example you can for each pointer dynamically allocate memory that will be pointed to by the corresponding pointer

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 3 };
    float  *coefficient[N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        coefficient[i] = malloc( sizeof( float ) );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        scanf( "%f", coefficient[i] );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%f\n", *coefficient[i] );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        free( coefficient[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
1.1
2.2
3.3
```

then the output will look like

```
1.100000
2.200000
3.300000
```

You can format the output as you like.

In general you should check that a call of `malloc` and/or of `scanf` was successful.

Comment: It seems like I have lately seen more questions (and answers!) using `int main() {...}` than ever before, and here OP code doesn't seem to acknowledge `main()` returning a value at all. Hmmm. Maybe it's a retro computing thing. IAC, it might be helpful to point out that more robust code checks for failure of `malloc()` and checks the value returned by `scanf()`.